# How do you annotate a flowtype of a function that returns a slice of state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype, typing, static-typing

**Background:**

currently, my `registerOneTarget` method is annotated to return the entire `LazyloadProviderState` and that is wrong because it is only returning a slice of the full state. my `registerOneTarget` method takes in a target and returns a **function that returns a slice of state**.

**Question:**

Inflow how do you annotate a single key of a larger type (`LazyloadProviderState`)? In other words, how can we explicitly type `LazyloadProviderState.targets` and not annotate the whole `LazyloadProviderState` type?

**State + Types:**

```
export type LazyloadProviderState = {
  targets?: TargetHash,
  otherProps: any,
  id: number,
  meta: any,
};

export type Hash = string;

export type TargetHashMap = {
  [key: Hash]: Target,
};

export type Target = {
  key: Hash,
  current: Node,
  visibility: boolean,
};
```

**Function with return type in question:**

```
static registerOneTarget(
    target
  ) : (LazyloadProviderState => LazyloadProviderState) // wrong!
  {
    return ps => {
      return {
        targets: {
          ...ps.targets,
          ...LazyloadProvider.createElement(target),
        },
      };
    };
  }
```

*Full class if it helps understand*

```
 class LazyloadProvider extends Component<
  LazyloadProviderProps,
  LazyloadProviderState
> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {targets: {}};
  }

  static createHash(): Hash {
    let d, r;
    return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, c => {
      r = (new Date().getTime() + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
      d = Math.floor(d / 16);
      return (c === 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3) | 0x8).toString(16);
    });
  }

  static createElement(target): TargetHash {
    const key = LazyloadProvider.createHash();
    const visibility = false;
    return {
      [key]: {
        ...target,
        key,
        visibility,
      },
    };
  }

  static registerOneTarget(
    target
  ): LazyloadProviderState => LazyloadProviderState {
    return ps => {
      return {
        targets: {
          ...ps.targets,
          ...LazyloadProvider.createElement(target),
        },
      };
    };
  }

  get engine() {
    return {
      state: this.state,
      register: target => {
        this.setState(LazyloadProvider.registerOneTarget(target));
      },
      deregister: target => {},
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <LazyloadContext.Provider value={this.engine}>
        {this.props.children}
      </LazyloadContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [$Shape](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-shape):

> Copies the shape of the type supplied, but marks every field optional.

So your function annotation will be:

```
LazyloadProviderState => $Shape<LazyloadProviderState>
```

Other (and I guess more straightforward) solution might be to extract the piece of returned state into separate type:

```
export type LazyloadProviderPartialState = {
  targets?: TargetHash,
};
```

And next you can define full type as contained the partial type:

```
export type LazyloadProviderState = { 
  otherProps: any,
  id: number,
  meta: any,
} & LazyloadProviderPartialState;
```

and then it becomes very easy to define the function:

```
LazyloadProviderState => LazyloadProviderPartialState;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to explicitly say what part of the state you are returning - `{targets: TargetHash}`

```
export type LazyloadProviderState = {
  targets?: TargetHash,
  otherProps: any,
  id: number,
  meta: any,
};

static registerOneTarget(
    target
  ) : (LazyloadProviderState => {targets: TargetHash})
  {
    return ps => {
      return {
        targets: {
          ...ps.targets,
          ...LazyloadProvider.createElement(target),
        },
      };
    };
  }
```